# Javascript function that changes various images onclick of one image

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

I have searched and tried out various functions including 'if' and 'else' functions, but I can't get them to work..

The intention is to change various images onclick of just one image. Here is the HTML for that image I'm currently using:

```
<div id="apDiv2"><a href="#" onclick="changeImg();"><img src="images/AJP-TAG-W.jpg" width="207" height="138" /></a></div>
```

I would like onclick of that image for these two images to be swapped

```
<div id="apDiv12"><a href="dancehall.html"><img src="images/Dancehall.jpg" width="240" height="74" alt="Dancehall" id="Dancehall" /></a></div>
```

and

```
<div id="apDiv6"><a href="house.html"><img src="images/House.jpg" width="240" height="74" alt="House" id="House" /></a></div>
```

Comment: You should add the code of your changeImg function or else people won't be able to find your problem. It also seems like you don't want to only change the images but also the href attribute of your anchor element. You should add this so it's bit more obvious for people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function changeImg() {
    var img1 = document.getElementById('apDiv12');
    var img2 = document.getElementById('apDiv6');
    var tmp = img1.innerHTML;
    img1.innerHTML = img2.innerHTML;
    img2.innerHTML = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using jQuery (https://code.jquery.com) and using the following function:

```
function changeImg()
{
    var tmp_src = $("#Dancehall").attr("src");
    $("#Dancehall").attr("src", $("#House").attr("src"));
    $("#House").attr("src", tmp_src);
}
```

Or the basic javascript solution:

```
function changeImg()
{
    var tmp_src = document.getElementById("Dancehall").src;
    document.getElementById("Dancehall").src = document.getElementById("House").src;
    document.getElementById("House").src = tmp_src;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide or show your divs with jQuery or basic Javascript.
Here is an jQuery example for you;

```
<div id="apDiv2"><a href="#" onclick="changeImg();"><img src="images/AJP-TAG-W.jpg" width="207" height="138" /></a></div>
<div style="display:none" id="apDiv12"><a href="dancehall.html"><img src="images/Dancehall.jpg" width="240" height="74" alt="Dancehall" id="Dancehall" /></a></div>
<div style="display:none" id="apDiv6"><a href="house.html"><img src="images/House.jpg" width="240" height="74" alt="House" id="House" /></a></div>
    <script>
    function changeImg(){
        $('#apDiv2').hide();
        $('#apDiv6').show();
        $('#apDiv12').show();
    }
    </script>
```